# Why I can't detect Media Queries in IE9 using modernizr

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, media-queries, modernizr

I searched support of CSS3 Media Queries in browsers, and IE9+ support it, http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries, but when I use **Modernizr** to detect it, it turns out, ie7-ie9 not support it, ie10 support it.
What I do is :

1. generate custom modernizr js: http://modernizr.com/download/#-mq-teststyles-load
2. html code: below is my code in the html head, I want to detect if the browser support for the min-width media query use, if it support, add support.js, if not, include nosupport.js

   ```
   <script src="modernizr.custom.03829.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
       Modernizr.load({
           test: Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 0px)'),
           yep: 'support.js',
           nope: 'nosupport.js'
       });
   </script>
   ```
3. In support.js: alert("support");
4. In nonosupport.js: alert("not support");

Result: ie7-ie9 alert "not support", in ie10, alert "support". I think ie9 also should alert "support", right?
Is there something wrong with my code?

Another weird thing is if I USE the sample usage from http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq
:

```
Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 768px)')  // true
```

Chrom, firefox and IE7-10 will alert "not support", I think modern browsers should alert "support". Why?

Answer (score 1):

On your first question - I am not able to replicate. `Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 0px)')` returns true in IE 9 for me. Check your document mode in the F12 tools to see if you are falling back to a non standards mode.

On your second, browser modernness has nothing to do with wether or not it will return true. `Modernizr.mq` tests if the browser matches a media query. If it is false, that means that the browser window is larger than 768 pixels.